# CSS Grid, ng-repeat and unknown data

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-grid

Here is the problem. The code is receiving data from a web service in a multidimensional array format. The number of rows and columns, and what those columns are called (keys) are also unknown until run-time. I need to display a grid of that data in a table-like structure. We would like to display this data using CSS Grid (no Tables).

For example, let's assume the following data is retrieved from a web service.

```
                var data = [
                    { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Doe' },
                    { id: 2, first: 'Jane', last: 'Davis' },
                    { id: 3, first: 'Steve', last: 'Smith' }
                ];
                vm.data = data;
```

Now, I need to display that in a CSS Grid format. First I define the containing DIV which has the 'display: grid' in the style, so that we have a CSS Grid.

```
<div style="display: grid;">...</div>
```

The desired HTML needs to look similar to the following. (Note that the actual order of the DIV's is of no matter to me, just as long as the grid-row and grid-column values are correct).

```
<div style="display: grid;">
  <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;">id</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;">first</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 3;">last</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 1;">1</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 2;">John</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 2; grid-column: 3;">Doe</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 3; grid-column: 1;">2</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 3; grid-column: 2;">John</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 3; grid-column: 3;">Doe</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 4; grid-column: 1;">3</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 4; grid-column: 2;">John</div>
  <div style="grid-row: 4; grid-column: 3;">Doe</div>
</div>
```

The website uses AngularJS, so one option is to use ng-repeat in order to generate the HTML. The problem is, ng-repeat is really meant to work with one-dimensional data. We can pull some additional data by using $index (for example) however.

So for example, in order to generate the DIV's to render the column Titles (which in this case, we are just going to use the Key names) I can do this:

HTML:

```
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat({{ vm.reportHeaders.length }}, 1fr); grid-gap: 10px;">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in reportingCtrl.data[0]" style="grid-column: {{ $index }}; grid-row: 1;">{{ key }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
var reportHeaders = [];
for (var property in data[0]) {
    if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       reportHeaders.push(property);
    }
}
vm.reportHeaders = reportHeaders;
```

So far so good, but now we come to the data, and that's where I'm getting stuck.

**In my mind, I need to:**

1. Loop through the data row by row to access the row index
2. Loop through the row, column by column, in order to get the correct column index and the data to be displayed
3. Generate a DIV tag that renders the correct row/col data in the "grid-column" and "grid-row" style properties, as well as the correct data for the row/col.

I'm not sure how to do this.

**Thoughts**

- I've seen references to ng-repeat-start/end which might be helpful here, but that still doesn't seem to address the lack of knowing how many columns are involved?
- I can add the table heading data to the data table in the code-behind if that makes life any easier?
- Perhaps there is a way to create a Counter in the ng-repeat as opposed to using $index?
- I could generate the HTML in code-behind and then display it or add it to the DOM, but that's not my preferred option.
- I'm open to ideas? Maybe I'm just too close to the trees to see the forest?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS Grid and Vanilla JavaScript.

Here is a CodePen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ethanryan/pen/mXYMNo)

I put an example with your HTML code refactored with CSS class names in a blue border, then a JavaScript version in a green border.

Code snippet:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first: "John",
    last: "Doe"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first: "Jane",
    last: "Davis"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first: "Steve",
    last: "Smith"
  }
];

function parseData() {
  var array = data.map(object => Object.values(object));
  return array; //this is an array of arrays
}

function outputData() {
  var data = parseData(); //this is an array of arrays
  var output_1 = document.getElementById("output-1");
  var output_2 = document.getElementById("output-2");
  var output_3 = document.getElementById("output-3");

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var array1 = data[i][0];
    var array2 = data[i][1];
    var array3 = data[i][2];
    
    var node1 = document.createElement("div");
    var node2 = document.createElement("div");
    var node3 = document.createElement("div");

    var id_column = array1;
    var firstName = array2;
    var lastName = array3;
    
    var textnode1 = document.createTextNode(id_column);
    var textnode2 = document.createTextNode(firstName);
    var textnode3 = document.createTextNode(lastName);

    node1.appendChild(textnode1);
    node2.appendChild(textnode2);
    node3.appendChild(textnode3);

    output_1.appendChild(node1);
    output_2.appendChild(node2);
    output_3.appendChild(node3);
  }
}
outputData();
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "d e f";
}
.one {
  grid-area: a;
}
.two {
  grid-area: b;
}
.three {
  grid-area: c;
}
.id {
  grid-area: d;
}
.first-name {
  grid-area: e;
}
.last-name {
  grid-area: f;
}
#blue-box {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#green-box {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hardcoded HTML with CSS classnames:
</p>

<div class="container" id="blue-box">
  <div class="one">id</div>
  <div class="two">first</div>
  <div class="three">last</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>John</div>
  <div>Doe</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>John</div>
  <div>Doe</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>John</div>
  <div>Doe</div>
</div>

<p>
  Dynamically generated via Vanilla JavaScript:
</p>

<div class="container" id="green-box">
  <div class="one">id</div>
  <div class="two">first</div>
  <div class="three">last</div>
  <div id="output-1" class="id">
  </div>
  <div id="output-2" class="first-name">
  </div>
  <div id="output-3" class="last-name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to solve this problem ([Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/ParaBolt/pen/OBERvP/)) :-

### Approach 1

We can use a hacky method to combine two ng-repeat directives - one for all items in data array and the other for all key-value pairs in an item.

For header generation, if you want object keys as titles and not custom titles, one approach is to use ng-repeat on key-value pairs for first item of the data array and to bind the keys to get the headers.

```
<div style="display:grid;">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.data[0]" style="grid-row:1; grid-col:{{$index+1}}">{{key}}</div>
    <div class="ng-hide" ng-repeat-start="(index, object) in vm.data"></div>
    <div ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="(key, value) in object" style="grid-row:{{index+2}}; grid-col:{{$index+1}}">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Key Takeaways :-

1. The two ng-repeats used are in a parent-child relationship. ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end pair is the parent.
2. The syntax (index, object) in vm.data allows us to store parent ng-repeat item indexes in a separate variable. Alternatively, we can use $parent.$index here. For child ng-repeat, we are using the $index variable.
3. Why index+2 for row? Indexes are 0-based and we already have row #1 for headers, so the loop will add rows starting from #2.
4. We need to take support of an additional div to acheive this structure. Hence, we use ng-hide to hide that extra div.

### Approach 2

We can flatten the collection into a primitive array and use ng-repeat for layout.

```
<div style="display:grid;">
    <div ng-repeat="(index, key) in vm.keys" style="grid-row:1; grid-col:{{index+1}}">{{key}}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="(index, value) in vm.values" style="grid-row:{{vm.calculateRow(index)}}; grid-col:{{(index%vm.keys.length)+1}}">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

In your JS :-

```
vm.currentRow = 0;
vm.keys = Object.keys(vm.data[0]);
vm.values = vm.data.reduce((array, object) => [...array, ...Object.values(object)], []);
vm.calculateRow = i => Math.floor(i/vm.data.length) + 2;
```

Key Takeaways :-

1. It is difficult to bind the original object to directives like ng-click.
2. Appending grid-row values requires additional logic which is performance-intensive.

---

**Notes**:

1. Both of the following solutions rely on iterating over the key/value pairs of objects in a collection. The iteration order is not guaranteed to be consistent across browsers.
2. We are assuming that the number of columns (object keys) will remain the same across each row (array item).

---

### On the CSS side of things

CSS grid is very flexible. In both of the above approaches, it is not necessary to specify the grid-row rule, the layouting system is smart enough to figure out when to create a new row. Alternatively, it is not necessary to inline row/col numbers on each div, since after getting the data you can compute the number of rows/columns, you could also specify that on the wrapper grid using the grid-template rule.

Eg :-

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template:repeat({{vm.rowCount}}, 1fr)/repeat({{vm.colCount}}, 1fr)"></div>
```